# Auth0 Angular: Detect if authenticated on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

What's the best way to detect whether the current session is authenticated when the page loads? Everything works fine when using `isAuthenticated` in the view, but when I access `$rootScope.isAuthenticated` in `module.run` or in any controller, it's always `false`.

I want to show the login modal (via `authService.login()`) If I detect that the user isn't logged in when the page loads.

Comment: Can you try using `auth.isAuthenticated` ?

Comment: @Abhishrek `auth` is undefined in the scope. `authService.isAuthenticated` is also undefined.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt/blob/e41753fbbff7991b5121790b18e78872302ec06c/src/angularJwt/services/authManager.js), there's no event that fires after the authentication check is made, so the only way to do it would be to wait an arbitrary amount of time to see if `authenticated()` is ever called.